# How to query jayson (nodejs) with curl

Tags: node.js, curl

I am trying to figured out how to query using CURL on the "jayson" npm package for nodejs available from here https://github.com/tedeh/jayson. I am using the test program below on the server side. Node is running properly and respond to Curl with an error output. no way to find what should be passed in Curl or what should be changed on the node program:

```
var jayson = require(__dirname + '/../..');
var server = jayson.server({
  echo: function(msg, callback) {
    if(msg != null)
      callback(null, msg);
  },
  add: function(a, b, callback) {
    if( (a!= null) && (b!= null) )
      callback(null, a + b);
  }
});
server.http().listen(90);
```

this is the CURL command:

```
$ curl -v -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "id":"curltest", "method":"echo", "params": ["hello"] }' http://localhost:90
```

and this is the nodejs answer received by Curl if the curl command is not compliant to jayson:

```
* About to connect() to localhost port 90 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* connected
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 90 (#0)
> POST / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.28.1
> Host: localhost:90
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 16
>
* upload completely sent off: 16 out of 16 bytes
* HTTP 1.1 or later with persistent connection, pipelining supported
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Length: 79
Content-Length: 79
< Content-Type: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
< Date: Tue, 25 Mar 2014 19:26:21 GMT
Date: Tue, 25 Mar 2014 19:26:21 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
Connection: keep-alive

<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":null,"error":{"code":-32600,"message":"Invalid request"}}* Closing connection #0
```

Many thanks for the help,
Rémi

Answer (score 0):

You are running the curl from windows. That's why the single quote around the parameters doesn't work for you. Change them into double quotes:

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"echo\": \"Name\"}" http://localhost:90/?
```

Also, try to run the command with `-v` appending at the end. It will show you the debug msg of curl. Show us the msg if it doesn't work for you.

Comment: Well thanks for the tentative! You are right by the way, I am using Curl from Cygwin. Unfortunately your fix gives me the same error. I have updated the description on your recommendation.

Comment: @user1680283 Your curl command is ok. Not it's up to the `node.js` bosses to take care of this problem!

Answer (score 0):

I found the trick and I have corrected the error above. We should be jsonrpc 2.0 compliant as Jayson is considering jsonrpc2 only.

This is the correct curl command line for the "echo" script:

```
$ curl -v -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "id":"curltest", "method":"echo", "params": ["hello"] }' localhost:90
```

This is the correct curl command line for the "add" script:

```
$ curl -v -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "id":"curltest", "method":"add", "params": [1, 2] }' http://localhost:90
```